# Setting initial on ModelChoiceField doesn't work within __init__

Tags: django, django-forms

Within Django there should be two ways of setting the initial value for a foreign key. My second approach doesn't seem to work for me and I don't understand why:

**Model:**

```
class Task(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True, blank=True)
```

***Works:***

**View:**

```
form = TaskForm(contact, instance=task, prefix='form', initial = {'contact' : contact.pk})
```

**Form:**

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, contact, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

---

***Doesn't work***:

**View:**

```
form = TaskForm(contact, instance=task, prefix='form')
```

**Form:**

```
class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, contact, *args, **kwargs):
        super(TaskForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if contact:        
            self.fields['contact'].initial = contact.pk

    class Meta:
        model = Task
```

Comment: `form = TaskForm(instance=task)` without overriding `__init__` [should be enough](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: Sorry what? You are not even setting the initial value for contact.

Comment: Thats correct if `task` is a variable with correct `task.contact`. If you want some __init__ magic, pass `contact` variable in `kwargs`.

Comment: I am not sure, if that would work. contact field is still a foreignkey to the Model `contact`. If you think you have the solution, please post it properly so I can tick it off.

Comment: Does `if contact` even fire? You are doing something very odd to the form signature.. it normally expects the first argument to be the data dictionary, so you'll have to remember to call `MyForm(contact, request.POST` to ensure your super call does the right thing.

Comment: @Kave, you're right. To set up initial value you should use your first version (except for pointless overriding of init method).